# How make code to simulate the command < file.txt

Tags: java

I'm developing java code that needs to simulate the following:

```
my_command < file.txt
```

I tested writing to STDIN but it doesn't seem to be the solution.

Has someone already developed it?

Note, in the below code,
`source` is an instance of `java.io.File`

```
String commandLine = "myCommand";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
new Thread(() -> {
    try (BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source)
     ){
        String line;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            stdin.write(line);
            System.out.print(line);
        }
        stdin.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();

int ret = process.waitFor();
```

FYI my command is `mysql`

Comment: so did you open that file ("file.txt") in java and wrote its contents to stdin, or did you just write "file.txt" to stdin? if former, please add your code to the question.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-process-api#3-getoutputstream)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (rather than class `Runtime`).

I don't know what your *my_command* is, so the below code uses [cleartool](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.1?topic=software-cleartool).

First I create the text file containing the *cleartool* subcommands that I wish to execute.

```
hostinfo
exit
```

(Note the empty last line of the file.)
I named this file `exits_ct.txt`

Now the java code that will run *cleartool* command, then enter the subcommands from the text file and print the command output to standard output.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PrcBldTs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cleartool");
        pb.redirectInput(new File("exits_ct.txt"));
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        try {
            Process proc = pb.start(); // throws java.io.IOException
            int result = proc.waitFor(); // throws java.lang.InterruptedException
            System.out.println("result: " + result);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
MY_COMP: ClearCase 9.0.0.0 (Windows NT 6.2 (build 9200)  Pentium)
result: 0
```